# use a bump in my salary

Tags: word-usage

In this [comic strip](https://safr.kingfeatures.com/api/img.php?e=gif&s=c&file=QmxvbmRpZS8yMDIwLzEwL0Jsb25kaWUuMjAyMDEwMTJfMTUzNi5naWY=), the man says "Boss, I could really **use a bump** in my salary."

It seems like that he is asking for a raise in his salary.
What does "**use a bump**" mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 pieces here...

## ... could (really) use a ...

This phrase means "I would like a ...", "I need a ...", or "I would be happy to get a ..."

## a bump in ...

A "bump" can mean 1 of 2 things: (1) a temporary increase (an extra $100 this month, back to normal next month), or (2) a small permanent increase (a raise in salary). In this case, he probably means (2) a raise.

## The whole meaning

Put them together and he means...

> I would like a (small) raise in my salary.

Comment: Thank you. Great help to me. I never thought "could use ..." could mean other than what it literally means.

Comment: A lot of things mean differently in phrases, like idioms & slang.